# Center an <a> element

Tags: css

I have an element in my header that is getting data from a js file.

I'm trying to center that element in my page but all i do dosent seem to work.

I tried margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto but still is not centering.

The element code is:

```
<a href="http://[ip]/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo" style="margin: 0px; display: block; ">Loading...</a>
```

> http://tranceil.fm

(the blue song info in the frame below the menu)

Any thoughts?

Comment: try giving a fixed width to the element since it's block. Then margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it (center the link using `text-align: center` in the parent container):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
    <a href="http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" 
    id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo" 
    style="margin: 0px; display:block;">Loading...</a>
</div>
```

Or simply add `text-align: center` to the element itself:

```
    <a href="http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" 
    id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo" 
    style="margin: 0 auto; display:block; text-align: center">Loading...</a>
```

```html
<!-- text-align: center directly on element -->
<a href="http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo" style="margin: 0 auto; display:block; text-align: center">Loading...</a>

<!-- text-align: center on parent container -->
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
  <a href="http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo" style="margin: 0px; display:block;">Loading...</a>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9pyj/1/)**

Comment: thanx chris..please look at my answer to see if this clarifies my meaning of what i need to achieve..thank you again :)

Comment: Gotcha - I'd use the example that has the centering set on the parent - it definitely won't move. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try encapsulating your A element in a div and adding the CSS text-align property:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls" id="cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo">Loading...</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use margin left and right with percentage. for more details look at the following tutorial:
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 1):

To center something in CSS, make sure the parent element has `position: relative`, and the element you want to center `position: absolute` and `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -width/2`. That's the basic idea to center elements horizontally. To center vertically you can use the same technique but with `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -height/2`, or if it's just text then set the `line-height` equal to the height of the container element.

Answer (score 1):

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: center; 
margin-left: 50%; 
margin-right: 50%; 
overflow: visible;
```

Comment: Please provide some information with your answer, and not just a code snippet. this can help OP to understand why this works and what was wrong with his train of thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width to your element like this:

```
#cc_strinfo_song_tranceilfm {
width: 90%;
clear: both;
margin: auto;
}
```